# ggplot - trendline based on full data set in a subset graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, trend

My dataset consists of data between -200 and 100% on the y-axis. 
Using the ylim(0,100) function I get rid of the negative values (which I want), however when using geom_smooth this function calculates the trend based only on the data which is shown in the ggplot.

Is there a way to make a trend using the full dataset while only showing the subset of data 0-100% in my ggplot?

Here is an simplified example by request;

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Group   Sample  Percentage
A   185 50
B   185 60
C   185 70
D   185 60
A   159 40
B   159 -20
C   159 50
D   159 45
A   265 -35
B   265 30
C   265 10
D   265 40
A   143 60
B   143 -30
C   143 70
D   143 75
", header = TRUE)
df1$Sample <- factor(df1$Sample)

ggplot() + 
  theme_light() + 
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(x = Sample, y = Percentage, color = Group), size = 2) + 
  geom_smooth(data = df1, aes(x = as.numeric(Sample), y = Percentage, color = Group), method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE) +
  ylab("(%)") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('orange2','red','purple','blue'))
```

When I use ggplot with my full data set I get these trends;
[image: full data graph]

when I use;

```
plot + ylim(0,100)
```

I get this graph;
[image: ylim graph]

I would like to show the trends of the first graph but limit the y-axis to show only points between 0-100 like this;
[image: endgame graph]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [reprex]: A minimal dataset which supports the question and the code you have tried.

Comment: It sounds like you are inheriting the data. You can identify what data to use as an argument in the `geom_smooth` function.

Comment: @markhogue how would I do that?

Comment: `geom_smooth(data=...)`  <-- easy as that!  Just feed your full dataset to `geom_smooth` and use the subset for the rest.

Comment: I am using the full dataset as you can see in the example above but the ylim subsets it, could you elaborate what you mean? @chemdork123

Comment: Ah... I see now one sec

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `xlim()` not only sets the limits of the axis, but ***throws away those datapoints that are outside the axis***.  You need to set limits using `coord_cartesian(xlim=)`.  Let me show you what I mean:

```
set.seed(1111)
df <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=rnorm(100))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula='y~x')
p
```

[image]

That line goes slightly up.  If we use `xlim()` to narrow the limits, we can pick two points that angle the line down, if `geom_smooth()` takes only those for the approximation:

```
p + xlim(49, 52)
```

[image]

As expected, the line now angles down.  If we want to maintain the rest of the datapoints in the data frame but just narrow our viewing area, use `coord_cartesian(xlim=)`:

```
p + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(49,52))
```

[image]

Looks good now.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for!