# Plotting a subsection of data on a linear regression graph, with the whole data set

Tags: r, ggplot2, static, linear-regression, visualization

I want to plot a smaller subsection of code with the whole data set on one plot. This is the code I'm trying to use.

```
mydata2 <- Exp1[6:10|1:149,]

ggplot(mydata2,aes(x = conc, y = abs,colour = id))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm,se = FALSE,colour = "black") +
  xlim(0, 11) +
  ylim(0, 1) +
  ylab("Absorbance") +
  xlab("Concentration (mM)") +
  theme_bw()
```

Any help on this would be wonderful

Comment: You need more detail for us to actually know what you want. "Smaller subsection" is not specific enough

Comment: OP, agree with @Oliver that we need more information to determine what you're looking for, but I think [this answer might be able to help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61636588/9664796).  When you are zooming in on a plot location of a larger plot, always use `coord_cartesian()` rather than `xlim()` and `ylim()`.  `xlim()` and `ylim()` zoom in and *throw out the other points*, while `coord_cartesian()` uses the other points in calculations, but just zooms in.  The result is that with `xlim()`, your `geom_smooth` line changes, and with `coord_cartesian()` it will not.